# Why would userdel report that a user is currently used by a process that is running as another user?

Tags: linux, bash

When attempting to delete userA, `userdel` reported that `userA` is currently used by  process 1296; however, `ps` reported that this process was running as userB.  userC ran `userdel`.

```
userdel: user **userA** is currently used by process 1296
(base) **userC**@server:/dir1/home$ ps -aux | grep 1296
**userB**  1296  0.0  0.0  21604  5096 pts/0    Ss   Jan02   0:00 /bin/bash -l
```

Distro name and version:

(base) userB@server:~$ uname -a
Linux server 4.15.0-135-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:38:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

(base) userB@server:~$ id userA
uid=1000(userA) gid=1000(userA) groups=1000(userA)

(base) userB@server:~$ id userB
uid=000000(userB) gid=000000(userB) groups=000000(userB),00(sudo),000(lxd),000(libvirt),0000000(groupB),00000(groupB)

NB: The number of 0s reflects the number of digits in the number.

Comment: Please provide more information such as: Distro name and version, output of `id usera` and `id userb`, `ps -aux --forest` output of the entire tree that 1296 exists in, and an `strace` of the `userdel`

Comment: It is possible that both `userA` and `userB` have the same UID.

Comment: When I attempt to do make that happen manually with useradd, I get an error that the UID is already in use. Stackhatter could have manually edited their /etc/passwd to have two users with the same UID, but in this case I am not able to replicate the original error message from the OP on my Alpine test VM, which is why I also asked for distro name and version.

Comment: Process 1296 has been killed; hence, we cannot provide the other requested details on it.